# Изменение курсора на странице на свой. JS

Tags: javascript

На стандартные курсоры я сделал кнопку, при нажатии вызывается функция аргументом которой является имя курсора; 
В функции присваивается к `body`. 
Что прописать в аргументе к функции чтобы менялся мой пользовательский курсор?

Или можно каким-то другим способом это сделать?

```js
function Cursor(vc) {
    var a = document.body;
    a.style.cursor=vc;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="" class="progress" onClick="Cursor('progress');" value="Применить">
```